# Default weighing criterion for gnuplot's 'lc palette'

Tags: gnuplot

I'm a novice in Gnuplot. Today I was plotting a simple txt file with two data columns, being the x and y coordinates of a cloud of points in the xy plane; I wanted to color them according to the position they occupied in the list, so I should have gone for something like:

> plot "data.txt" u 1:2:0 lc palette

that produces what I want:
[(desired plot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clwdj.png)

By mistake, I omitted the "using" part of the command, so that I prompted:

> plot "data.txt" lc palette

Now, the points still are plotted in the correct positions, so that gnuplot is automatically interpreting them as (x,y) coordinates... but the colors look like this:
[(strangely colored plot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMjE4.png)

I find this baffling since there's the possibility that I'm involuntarily highlighting some interesting feature of my data (which, by the way, consists of few iterations of a discrete recurrence for a set - the x=1.57 line you can see -  of different initial conditions.

The question is: what criterion does 'lc palette' use to assign the parity I see to my points? What is its default behavior supposed to be in this case?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I don't know if it can be useful, but prompting 'show palette' I get:

```
palette is COLOR
rgb color mapping by rgbformulae are 7,5,15
figure is POSITIVE
all color formulae ARE NOT written into output postscript file
allocating ALL remaining color positions for discrete palette terminals
Color-Model: RGB
gamma is 1.5
```

Comment: You must have a very old version of gnuplot.  Current and even not-so-current versions return the error message "Not enough columns for variable color".  I imagine you were seeing whatever random junk was present in an internal data field that was not initialized.